# How do I incorporate robolectric into an existing Android Studio project?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric

The android ecosystem, particularly Android Studio, has been changing a lot over the last year or so.  I've found many sets of instructions for incorporating robolectric into a project, written at many points during that period.  And I haven't yet made one work on my project.

Which commands do I need to add to my app build.gradle?

Which commands do I need to add to my project build.gradle?

Do I need to use Junit 4 in order to use robolectric?

Are there other libraries needed?  What versions?

Do my tests need to be in src/test rather than src/androidTest?

What other information do I need?

I'm using:

- Android Studio 1.1.0
- gradle 1.1.0
- junit 4.12
- hamcrest-library 1.3
- mockito-core 1.10.19
- dexmaker 1.0
- dexmaker-mockito 1.0

Comment: The major question from me - are you using any support libraries?

Comment: @EugenMartynov I would be happy to use whatever libraries will best do the job.  Do you recommend any, or recommend avoiding any?  I think the list in the original question gives a fair representation of what I've got in the project.

Comment: Carl, I have issues now with Robolectric, android-assertj, android gradle plugin 1.1.0 and support library. And the main issue is in loading support resources by Robolectric. My answer will follow soon

Comment: @EugenMartynov Do you explain your issues somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you expect to run tests from Android Studio in addition to be able run them from command line only.

I think the most up to date example of usage Robolectric with latest android gradle plugin is [this](https://github.com/nenick/AndroidStudioAndRobolectric).

One note: I see dependencies to `dexmaker` and `dexmaker-mockito` that gives me assumption that you use Instrumental tests instead of plain junit tests.

It is quite dumb answer with just reference but I can not be more specific until you have specific issue